# Photodiode to Arduino interface for high lux measurement

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, adc, photodiode, proteus

I'm trying to create a photodiode interface for my Arduino Uno board that can measure very high lux values. This is to be part of my lightcontroller project for monitoring high wattage lamps (~1000w). I've made the following design to simulate this in Proteus, but since I don't own a lux-meter, I don't have a faintest clue how much current will go through the photodiode when exposed to a 1000w lamp.

Could I go with this approach in real-life?

Any suggestions/comments would be most appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Heat from the lamp will increase dark current which will make readings inaccurate so what distance are you planning to use? Also why are you not using a conventional PD transconductance amplifier?

Comment: Thanks for quick response! The light-fixture is fan-cooled, thus would never exceed ~40 degC. I was planning on mounting the photodiode into this fixture through a hole in one end to make it point at the other end of the inside (on a white surface). So not pointed directly at the lamp, but indirect.

Why not using transconductance amplifier.. good question! It's just that I've got so many mcp6002s laying around, I thought I could make use of them... :) Could you recommend a suitable trans. amp. to use? Perhaps you know of any schematics also?

Regards, Karl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A transimpedance amplifier is the circuit of choice for combining high sensitivity and high speed. Since neither seems necessary (EDIT - and your C1 guarantees no high speed), your approach seems adequate. A few suggestions:

1) There is no obvious reason to include your bias resistor. On the one hand, you're running your photodiode in photovoltaic mode, so bias should not be important. On the other hand, you're running at high levels (~1 mA in your schematic) so dinking around with a few microamps doesn't seem worth the effort.

2) There is no need for your voltage follower, since the output simply feeds the + input of the gain amp, and there is no need to make the impedance change. That is, the gain amp has exactly the same input impedance as the follower, so you don't gain anything.

3) Frankly, I'd also get rid of the zener as unnecessary. Where, exactly, do you think high voltage is going to come from? The photodiode? You should read the data sheet (even better, provide us a link). For most signal photodiodes, as opposed to solar cells, a saturation current of about 10 mA applies. But you can leave it in if you like.

4) And most importantly, you'll need to do some experimenting to determine just exactly what sort of light intensities you'll be dealing with. Nominally, noon sunlight has a brightness of about 100,000 lux, and a total optical power of about 1000W/m^2. However, this is about 8% UV, 40% visible, and 50% IR. An incandescent lamp, of course, will have a somewhat different overall output curve (no UV to speak of, different peak wavelength, no atmospheric absorption of IR), and at this point I have no information about the response curve of your photodiode, its area, or the distance it will be from the lamps being measured. As a result, it's impossible to predict what the out of the photodiode will be. And that's why you need to do some measuring.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and elaborate answer! I'm starting to get it :) Just one question; do you know of any photodiode that sure is capable of measuring that high of a range, or do I have to make some sort of "filter" to place over it to compensate? Btw, the photodiodes I currently have are of those cheap Chinese ones ICA077 and I can't find any datasheet on those...

Comment: I've updated my schematic. If I omit R2 (bias?), it won't work though.. http://imagebin.ca/v/2HBdVrzBDGRP

Is this better? Regards, Karl

Comment: "If I omit R2 (bias?), it won't work though" Don't tease. Exactly how doesn't it work? What voltages do you get at the op amp inputs and outputs? What is the pot set at?